# Recommendation System with ALS Implicit

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, recommender-system, kaggle

I created a model for Recommending top 10 items to users similar to the approach used here https://github.com/benfred/implicit/blob/master/examples/lastfm.py

I wanted to evaluate the model using NDCG Metric. But I am not sure how to implement it. Can somebody help with it?